# How can I prevent the user from going to admin panel using authorization if he directly enters the url to admin home in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have made two different controllers i.e. Users Controller and Admins Controller. Whenever i authenticate user it can go to its homepage and do whatever it wants and **i want to prevent these users to enter to the admin panel** if they directly inputs the path to the admin panel.

How can i do it in the users policy??

I am using role based login in Users table.

this is my users policy file contents.

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Policy;

use App\Model\Entity\User;
use Authorization\IdentityInterface;
use Authorization\Policy\Result;



class UserPolicy
{
    public function canCreate(IdentityInterface $user, User $resource)
    {

        return true;
    }


    public function canUpdate(IdentityInterface $user, User $resource)
    {

                return $this->isAuthor($user, $resource);

    }


    public function canDelete(IdentityInterface $user, User $resource)
    {

        return false;

    }


    public function canView(IdentityInterface $user, User $resource)
    {

    }

    public function canHome(IdentityInterface $user, User $resource){

                return $this->isAuthor($user, $resource);

    }
    public function canProfile(IdentityInterface $user, User $resource){

            return $this->isAuthor($user, $resource);

    }
    public function canAdmin(IdentityInterface $user, User $resource){

        return false;
    }


     protected function isAuthor(IdentityInterface $user,User $resource)
    {
        return $user->id === $user->getIdentifier();
    }
}

?>
```

I am very new to cakephp so please forgive me if its a silly question.

Comment: If you don't need all the can* complexity, you can also check if [TinyAuth](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-tinyauth) helps here to keep things simple. One line and you got what you need.